# All the widgets disappear when window size is decreased

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

When I decrease the window size all the widgets disappear.I want the widgets to move along when size is decreased.How do I solve this problem?

I have a drop-down menu from which a value is selected.When an "Add cmd" button is pressed the value is added to edit box.

Thanks in advance.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class tabdemo(QTabWidget):
   def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(tabdemo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400,400)

        QShortcut(QKeySequence("Esc"), self, self.close)
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.addTab(self.tab1,"Tab 1")
        self.tab1UI()
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")

   def tab1UI(self):
        self.comboBox = QComboBox(self.tab1)    
        self.comboBox.addItem('ABC')        
        self.comboBox.addItem('BCD')
        self.comboBox.addItem('CDE')
        self.comboBox.move(5,20)
        self.comboBox.resize(180,30)    

        self.button = QPushButton('Add Cmd', self.tab1)
        self.button.move(190,20)
        self.button.resize(80,30)   
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleTest)

        self.b = QTextEdit(self.tab1)
        self.b.move(20,75)
        self.b.resize(290,200)

        self.button = QPushButton('Send Batch', self.tab1)
        self.button.move(40,300)
        self.button.resize(150,30)  

        self.button = QPushButton('Clear', self.tab1)
        self.button.move(200,300)
        self.button.resize(80,30)   
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.deletevalue)   

        layout = QFormLayout()
        self.setTabText(4,"BatchCMDS")
        self.tab1.setLayout(layout)

   def handleTest(self):
        self.b.append(str(self.comboBox.currentText()))         

   def deletevalue(self):
        self.b.clear()

def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = tabdemo()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: [Put all the widgets in a layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: Thank you@ekhumoro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the widgets to adapt to the size of the window you should use [layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), For this, the application must be designed, for this an image is used of how you want your application to be:

[image]

As we see the widgets that are inside a tab are divided into 3 groups, the first is made up of the `QComboBox` with the `QPushButton`, the second the `QTextEdit`, and the third the 2 remaining buttons. Each group is horizontally distributed, so in that case we should use QHBoxLayout except the `QTextEdit` that is alone, and each group should be in `QVBoxLayout`. I do not understand why you use the `QFormLayout`, also if you use the layouts the positions are not necessary.

Another error that I see in your code is that several buttons have the same name, this causes errors like for example that the `Add CMD` button does not work, you must give a different name to each widget.

```
class tabdemo(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(tabdemo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400,400)

        QShortcut(QKeySequence("Esc"), self, self.close)
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.addTab(self.tab1,"Tab 1")
        self.addTab(self.tab2,"Tab 2")
        self.tab1UI()

    def tab1UI(self):
        vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.tab1)

        hlayout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.comboBox = QComboBox(self.tab1)    
        self.comboBox.addItems(['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE'])

        self.button = QPushButton('Add Cmd', self.tab1)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleTest)

        hlayout1.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        hlayout1.addWidget(self.button)
        hlayout1.addItem(QSpacerItem(100, 10, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Preferred))

        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout1)

        self.b = QTextEdit(self.tab1)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.b)

        hlayout2 = QHBoxLayout()

        self.buttonSend = QPushButton('Send Batch', self.tab1)
        self.buttonClear = QPushButton('Clear', self.tab1)
        self.buttonClear.clicked.connect(self.deletevalue)

        hlayout2.addItem(QSpacerItem(100, 10, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Preferred))
        hlayout2.addWidget(self.buttonSend)
        hlayout2.addWidget(self.buttonClear)
        hlayout2.addItem(QSpacerItem(100, 10, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Preferred))

        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout2)
        self.setTabText(4,"BatchCMDS")

    def handleTest(self):
        self.b.append(self.comboBox.currentText())         

    def deletevalue(self):
        self.b.clear()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @eyllanesc.